# How to create follower and followee in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I'm quite stuck in in Ruby on Rails relations and I really appreciate you help.

Have model **User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers, :through => :follows, foreign_key: "followee_id"
  has_many :followees, :through => :follows, foreign_key: "follower_id"
end
```

and model **Follow**

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followee, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
end
```

but if want to create new follower like:

```
user.followers << User.first
```

the result is SystemStackError

Thank you for every help!

Comment: Instead of `foreign_key: "followee_id"` you should use `source: :followee`

Answer (score 1):

You have to try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :follower_follows, foreign_key: :followee_id, class_name: "Follow" 
      has_many :followers, through: :follower_follows, source: :follower
      has_many :followee_follows, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: "Follow"
      has_many :followees, through: :followee_follows, source: :followee
    end
```

Here follower_follows and followee_follows are join tables and source: :follower matches with the belong_to :follower identification in the Follow model and source: :followee matches with the belong_to :followee identification in the Follow model

I think this would work in your case